# C++ inline closure analogue

Tags: c++, closures, inline

A function executes a certain block of code twice: for cnt = 0 and cnt = 1. Currently I use the following implementation:

```
int func {
    int V1, V2, ... , Vn;

    #define cnt 0
        // a block of code: some operations with V1, ... , Vn
    #undef cnt

    #define cnt 1
        // the same block of code
    #undef cnt
}
```

This code is quite ugly. Using an inline function would lead to an even uglier piece of code: I'd need to pass all the variables involved to a function by reference. Thus I'd like to create some kind of closure.

I cannot use something like

```
struct Nested {
    __forceinline void block(const int cnt) {
        // block of code
    };
};
```

because V1, ... , Vn shouldn't be made static for performance reasons.

I tried using a lambda function but Visual C++ 2013 fails to inline it even with inlining set to "Any Suitable (/Ob2)" (even with PGO) and that also hurts performance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with a `for` loop?

Comment: How do you store the lambda?  You don't use a `std::function` do you?

Comment: For loop cannot be used for performance reasons; moreover, there are variables like var_0/var_1 which are accessed with macros #define Var(cnt) ((cnt == 0) ? var##_0 : var##_1).

Comment: I tried using lambda in the following way: auto block = [&](const int cnt) { };

Comment: @user2419798: *for cannot be used for performance reasons*? Have you measured it? What compiler do you have that cannot unroll a for of precisely 2 iterations?

Comment: Is the `for` loop known to cause bad performance? That would be a big surprise to me.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In my experience, MSVC is rather bad with unrolling fixed-size loops.

Comment: On the problem with the for loop. If I replace int var_0, var_1 with int var[2] it's gonna be stored in stack instead of registers, right? That means performance drop. The block also contains operations like value += (cnt ? 1 : -1) which will obviously cause a slowdown if cnt is not a constant

Comment: @user2419798 The compiler will probably do the right thing. Have you *measured* the for loop? Did you examine the assembler code?

Comment: @user2419798: Have you measured?

Comment: No, I didn't measure the performance of a for loop, but there will be a slowdown just due to additional branching and it's a performance-critical part of the program.

Comment: @user2419798 If you have not measured, you are probably wasting a lot of resources ... somewhere else.

Comment: I mean {value -= 1; value += 1;} is significantly faster than for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 1; cnt++) value += (cnt ? 1 : -1); Unrolling'd solve this but it cannot be forced (as far as I know).

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
struct func_impl
{
  int V1, V2, ..., Vn;
  int res;

  template <int cnt>
  void blockOfCode() {
    ...
  }
};

int func()
{
  func_impl f;
  f.blockOfCode<0>();
  f.blockOfCode<1>();
  return f;
}
```

This should be equivalent to your `#define` solution.

**EDIT** In comments, you mentioned you also have variables like `var ## cnt`. These could be replaced with a two-element array, using the template argument `cnt` to index them:

```
int var[2];
var[cnt] = ...;
```

Comment: In this case V1,V2,... will not be stored in registers, right? So that's going to hurt performance.

Comment: @user2419798 As with all performance questions concerned with such fine level of detail - try it and see (and measure).

Comment: In the worst case scenario the problem can be solved with some performance loss. The question is whether it's possible to make the code more clean and compact while retaining the same speed.